# Only use subset of pods for child target

Tags: ios, cocoapods, ios8-share-extension, ios-targets

Is there a way to only use a subset of pods for a child target of an app (e.g. a share extension of my app)

I tried doing it this way:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!
I18n.enforce_available_locales = false

def all_pods
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3'
    pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger', '~> 2.0.2'
    pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding', '~> 1.2.3'
    pod 'SMPageControl', '~> 1.2'
    pod 'MLPAutoCompleteTextField', :git => 'https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField.git', :branch => 'master'
    pod 'UIImage-Resize', '~> 1.0.1'
    pod 'M13BadgeView', '~> 1.0.0'
    pod 'CWStatusBarNotification', '~> 2.3.3'
end

target 'Lohi Connect' do
    all_pods
    target 'Lohi Connect Share' do
       pod 'MLPAutoCompleteTextField', :git => 'https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField.git', :branch => 'master'
    end
end
```

however when I try to build my app it appears that all pods are used for the share extension which leads to crashes because some pods use `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` which is not available in share extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to end the instance of one target before assigning the second target.

please replace above code by the following:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!
I18n.enforce_available_locales = false

def all_pods
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3'
    pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger', '~> 2.0.2'
    pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding', '~> 1.2.3'
    pod 'SMPageControl', '~> 1.2'
    pod 'MLPAutoCompleteTextField', :git => 'https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField.git', :branch => 'master'
    pod 'UIImage-Resize', '~> 1.0.1'
    pod 'M13BadgeView', '~> 1.0.0'
    pod 'CWStatusBarNotification', '~> 2.3.3'
end

target 'Lohi Connect' do
    all_pods
end
target 'Lohi Connect Share' do
       pod 'MLPAutoCompleteTextField', :git => 'https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField.git', :branch => 'master'
end
```

Comment: that's what I tried myself first, but that gives me the error: ``Error:linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)``

Comment: @Max90 Check the whole error message the classes impacted. You might have used a class of "Lohi Connect" that use one of the others pods in "Lohi Connect Share". Separe them.